# Upgrade Delete Function in Inventory For Text Based Game

Tags: c++

I am still a newbie at C++, but I am currently working on a text based game. For my game, I have an Inventory that works, but I want to add a couple functions to it so it is better. I have tried googling around, but I can't find enough help or resources for me to be able to do this myself.

The first thing I am trying to do is when I use my delete function. For the function, I am having the user enter the item they wish to remove from their inventory. I want to be able to check that the user enters an item that exists in their inventory and not make an item up. So after the user enters the item, I take that item and go through the list, check to see if it is there, and then if it is there, delete it, and if it is not there print out an error message.

This is my code so far:

```
void Inventory::DeleteItem()
{
    string deleteitem = " ";

    if (item_numbers == 0) {
        cout << "\nError: No items in the Inventory.\n\n";
    }
    else {
        cout << "\nPlease type the item you wish to use or take out of the inventory: ";
        cin >> deleteitem;
    }
    bool found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i<item_numbers && !found; i++) {
        if (Info[i].item_name == deleteitem) {
            while(found == true){
                cout<<"Found an item matching what you wrote: "<<Info[i].item_name<<endl;
                item_numbers--;
                cout<<"Item: "<<Info[i].item_name<< " is now gone." <<endl;
                break;
            }
        }
         if (found == false){
            cout<<"liar"<<endl;
            break;
            }

    }
}
```

I bet the solution is so simple and I am missing it. I just honestly can't see it. I'm sorry! But I appreciate all the help!

Currently when I test the code, this is how it prints out:

```
Which item will you be adding to your inventory?  Here

Which item will you be adding to your inventory?  Now

Please type the item you wish to use or take out of the inventory: Here
liar
```

Comment: Your code never triggers the while loop because `found` always equals `false`

Comment: so should I change it to bool found; ? because I just tried that and it still is not working @JakeFreeman

Comment: First you do not remove the item from the array, second why are you using a while loop in the first place.

Comment: I think I had been playing around, but I was originally using an if. Whoops

Comment: Not sure what `Info` is, but consider replacing it with `std::map<std::string, TypeOfInfoElements> Info;` With a `map` you can map the item name to the item and perform lookup like `Info.find(deleteitem);` much less fuss and room for error. Docs on `std::map`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

Comment: You  could also use a `vector` @user4581301 perhaps that would be better in this situation.

Comment: Okay so I moved the bool found to the top next to my string deleteitem. And I changed the while to an it. It still isn't working... Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Performance-wise it depends on how much stuff you have in the list, but  I like to be able to keep the code simple and it doesn't get much simpler than  `auto it = Info.find(deleteitem);` No loops, not tests other than making sure `it != Info.end()` before using `it`.  I'm lazy.

Comment: @Candy move the liar if statement after the for loop

Comment: @JakeFreeman I tried that and its not working yet.

Comment: @user4581301 If you could, could you explain this auto a bit more? I don't really know how to implement that, sorry.

Comment: Auto allows you to hold any variable type

Comment: `auto` allows the compiler to infer the correct type for the variable from the initializer. Once the type is set, it cannot be changed, so you can't quite say it holds any type.  Docs on `auto`:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto

Comment: I tried using the auto, but I keep getting errors. I am not sure where I am going wrong on this either. Sorry! @user4581301

Comment: very poor title.  You should have done some basic debugging and give a more meaningful subject.  No one care you are "upgrading" a function, it means nothing to anyone that it is a "delete inventory function" and the question has nothing related to a "text based game".  Meaningful example are like: "Fail to find element in an array" or "How to remove an element in array"

Comment: and learn to use a debugger, and trace through your code once.  You should be able to find the problem easily.  The `while(found == true)` bunch of thing just does not make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't delete it in the way you thought the program.
I have done something similar a while ago and my advice is:
 1. Use another class "`Item`" with attribute "`Name`" and "`NumberOfItems`"(or more if you want);
 2. In the `Inventory` class add an attribute "`vector<Items> MyItems`" (it this way you learn about `vector` as well)
 3. when you find the object in your list, you call `MyItems.erase(position)`, where `position` is the index of your found item.